# Line-Breaking Around \clearpage

Tags: line-breaking, clearpage

AFAIK, line-breaking around `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, or `\begin{section}` doesn't change the results as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
                        % INSERTING OR DELETING THIS LINE DOESN'T AFFECT THE OUTCOME
\begin{document}
                        % INSERTING OR DELETING THIS LINE DOESN'T AFFECT THE OUTCOME
Hello, world!
                        % INSERTING OR DELETING THIS LINE DOESN'T AFFECT THE OUTCOME
\end{document}
```

I wonder if this is the same for `\clearpage`. I think there are seven possible spots for `\clearpage` that seemingly produce the same output. Do they have no logical difference from one another?

**Spot 1:** The spot *right after* the first paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.\clearpage

This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\end{document}
```

**Spot 2:** The spot *right below* the first paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\clearpage

This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\end{document}
```

**Spot 3:** *Two lines away* from both the first and second paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.

\clearpage

This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\end{document}
```

**Spot 4:** The spot *right above* the second paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.

\clearpage
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\end{document}
```

**Spot 5:** The spot *right before* the second paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.

\clearpage This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\end{document}
```

**Spot 6:** In the *middle* of the two paragraphs with no additional line break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\clearpage
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\end{document}
```

**Spot 7:** Just at the *beginning* of the second paragraph with no line break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\clearpage This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence. This is a sentence.
\end{document}
```

I think either **Spot 1** or **Spot 3** is more readable than others, and **Spot 7** is the shortest code among all the candidates with the same outcome. I wonder if pursuing easy-reading (or space-saving sometimes) coding practice unexpectedly influences the results.

Comment: Why should there be a difference? I don't think there is. LaTeX puts every paragraph in a box, then typesets the boxes vertically one after the other. `\clearpage` creates a new page in which the next box will be printed, the spaces don't matter much. I would use 1 or 3 for readability, but really, it's up to you.

Comment: @EladDen paragraphs are not boxed: (try your reasoning with `\pagebreak` instead of `\clearpage` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike  `\pagebreak`, `\clearpage` (via `\newpage`)  inserts a `\par` before processing, and after processing is consequently already in vertical mode.  this means that putting a blank line (`\par`) before or after makes no difference.
However a blank line is the standard document markup for paragraph breaks so I would always add a blank line between paragraphs (doesn't really matter whether that is before or after the clearpage) rather than rely on the technical detail that `\clearpage` ends the current paragraph.

If you try your examples with `\pagebreak` instead of `\clearpage` you will see  a big difference between the cases with the versions with no blank line being set as a single paragraph, not two.